# How dots indicate and manipulate slider with images

Tags: javascript, function, slider, indicator

I'm trying to build active dots for my slider and I found some reference on w3schools but I don't understand the logic behind the function that controls the dots. Anyone can explain to me how they work into the code below?

To mention: I know how the slider works ,but i don't understand how dots works!

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When one of the dots are clicked the method currentSlide is called with a corresponding parameter. The method showSlides is then called (with the same parameter) which does the following:

- saves the collection of elements with class name mySlides and dot into
  two variables:

> ```
> var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
> var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
> ```

For more info:

[getElementsByClassName() Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

- if the passed parameter is bigger or smaller than the number of slides (if for example more dots exists than slides), then the index of the slide that will be displayed is set to value in order to still display a slide

> ```
> if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
> if (n < 1) {slideIndex =slides.length}
> ```

- the value of property display is set to none for each slide

> ```
> for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
>       slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
>   }
> ```

For more info:

[Style display Property Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp)

[CSS display Property Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

- class active is removed from all dots

> ```
> for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
>       dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
>   }
> ```

- value of property display is set to block for the corresponding slide

> slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

- class active is added to the clicked dot

> dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";

I hope this is enough :)

Comment: Man,can you please look 2 seconds at my code  posted below?